# TM-V71A Echolink - Constantly Transmitting

Tags: kenwood, echolink

I just got a Kenwood TM-V71A, and I really want to use it for Echolink operation as a simplex node. I got it mostly working, but there's one huge problem - it's constantly transmitting over the Internet when there's no signal. I was testing on ECHOTEST. Basically it goes: RX -> Idle 1 sec -> TX until it gets a signal over RF and that signal goes away -> Idle 1 sec -> RX. TX/RX are based on Echolink (i.e. RX means the radio is transmitting what Echolink receives). Does anybody have any ideas what's causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: What are your settings on the receive configuration tab?

Comment: This sounds like local rfi and/or input/output freqs being misconfigured

Comment: Duncan W8MPX here I know this post is old but do you figure the KENWOOD V 71A I know this radio from A to Z and I can help you setup for EchoLink if need help call me at 216-633-6355

Comment: @W8MPX Welcome to this site! If you can answer this here, then others could benefit from your experience.